# What is the infinite dual space of a vector space?

Tags: functional-analysis, dual-spaces

Given an infinite dimensional vector space, $V$, its dual space, $V^*$, is larger than $V$ and its double dual even bigger (usually). If you keep on going with the triple and quadruple dual, what happens? Taking the limit of the system where $V_0=V$ and $V_i=V_{i-1}^{**}$ with the morphisms being the canonical injections from a space into its double dual, what would the [direct limit](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_limit) be? And also correct me if this isn’t the proper way to formulate this, category theory isn’t my strong suit.

Comment: As written, what you say is not true. There are topological vector spaces $V$ such that $V^*=\{0\}$. Are you talking about algebraic duals? Are you talking about normed spaces and continuous duals?

Comment: @MartinArgerami that’s why I said usually.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Why would you bring up topological vector spaces when the OP don't mention that at all? It's clear from the question that the OP is talking about the algebraic dual.

Comment: @jjagmath: the question is tagged "functional analysis". You don't do algebraic duals in Functional Analysis.

Comment: @jjagmath It is clear from the comments that OP means continuous dual (of normed soaces) and not algebraic dual. See why there is confusion?